# How to write catalog with many categories(taxonomy >>100)?

Tags: go

I am newbie to golang, who moved from dynamic typed language.

I faced with problem how to  write catalog with many categories/subcategory — complex taxonomy. For example:

Shoestring > Shoes > Men > shoes > clothes > Home > Categories

I am using mongodb as backend. I can't understand **how to write CRUD operation's in this case?**

***If I will process all queries as usual***:

```
func RunFindAllQuery(document interface{}, m bson.M, mongoSession *mgo.Session, conn Conn) (err error) {
sessionCopy := mongoSession.Copy()
defer sessionCopy.Close()
collection:= sessionCopy.DB(conn.Database).C(conn.Collection)   
err = collection.Find(m).All(document)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("RunQuery : ERROR : %s\n", err)
}
   return err
}
```

I will need to define many types: shoes != car.

```
type Shoes struct {
    Id             bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
    Name           string        `bson:"name"`
    Description    string        `bson:"descriprion"`
    Size           float         `bson:"size"`
    Color          float         `bson:"color"`
    Type           float         `bson:"type"`
    ShoeHeight     float         `bson:"shoeheight"`
    PlatformHeight float         `bson:"platformheight"`
    Country        float         `bson:"country"`
}
type Car struct {
    Id          bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
    Name        string        `bson:"name"`
    Model       CarModel      `bson:"name"`
    Description string        `bson:"descriprion"`
    Color       float         `bson:"color"`
    Height      float         `bson:"height"`
    Fueltype    string        `bson:"fueltype"`
    Country     float         `bson:"country"`
}
```

And my code will be copypaste:

```
var carobjFindAll []Car
m := bson.M{"description": "description"}
_ = RunFindAllQuery(&carobjFindAll, m, mongoSession, conn)
for cur := range carobjFindAll {
    fmt.Printf("\nId: %s\n", carobjFindAll[cur].Id)
    fmt.Printf("\nColor: %s\n", carobjFindAll[cur].Color)
}
var shoesobjFindAll []Shoes
m_shoes := bson.M{"description": "shoes_description"}
_ = RunFindAllQuery(&shoesobjFindAll, m_shoes, mongoSession, conn)
for cur_shoe := range shoesobjFindAll {
    fmt.Printf("\nId: %s\n", shoesobjFindAll[cur_shoe].Id)
    fmt.Printf("\nColor: %s\n", shoesobjFindAll[cur_shoe].Color)
}
```

PS:
Sorry for my English

Comment: Broadly, you want products and categories to have a `Categories` field with an array of category IDs (because on real ecommerce sites, items tend not to be in just one category) and a [multikey index](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/index-multikey/) so you can find all products/subcategories in a category. I'm not a Mongo guy and it's a broad question, so that's all I've got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a MongoDB expert, but here is my take:

As you have plenty of categories, you don't have any itnerest in writing a struct for each of your types, as it would be both fastidious and unreliable.

Instead, you should work directly with the `bson.M` type, which is basically an alias for the `map[string]interface{}` type.